# Isoperimetric inequality for Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I want to ask if the isoperimetric inequality of the following form holds.

Let's suppose that $(\mathbb{R}^n, g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with $0 < Vol_g(A) < \infty$ and let $B_g(0, r)$ be the ball (with respect to $g$) centered at the origin with the radius $r$ such that $Vol_g(A) = Vol_g(B_g(0, r))$. Then $Per_g(A) \geq Per_g(B_g(0,r))$.

I think this is true but I couldn't find any literature. Please give any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curvature throws a spanner in the works here - for example if $g$ is flat near the origin but has a region of constant positive curvature elsewhere, then choosing $A$ to be an appropriate ball in this positively curved region will violate your inequality. I think you need to assume a Ricci curvature bound and then compare to balls in the corresponding space of constant curvature rather than comparing to balls about $0$. Search for the "Levy-Gromov Isoperimetric Inequality".